# Im getting a decimal place on the on the final age using LUA how to conver into whole number

Tags: lua

im trying to make the age as a whole number because im currently getting a decimal place.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

To convert a float to a number string with `0` decimals use `string.format("%.0f", yourFloat)`

Please refer to [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format)